# Component loads before redux change the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to render the main page of my application, and to load the information for the components to use I'm fetching a json-server to update my state via redux. the problem is that when I load the application through the url: localhost: 3000, my main page component does not recognize the items that it needs to recognize from the state.
it looks like it reads the initial state, which is empty. I think the component is trying to read the state before it is updated. I'm dispatching to change the state in App.js, my main component. any idea what it might be? the application is working, but only if I boot from another page and go to the main page. Any idea?

my reducer:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialAnuncios = [];

export const fetchAnuncios = createAsyncThunk('anuncios/fetchAnuncio',
    async () => {
        return await (await fetch('http://localhost:8000/anuncios')).json();
    });


function fullfillAnunciosReducer(initialState, anunciosFetched) {
    return anunciosFetched;
}

export const anunciosSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'anuncios',
    initialState: initialAnuncios,
    reducers: {
        setKeyAnuncioAtual: (state, action) => ({ ...state, keyAnuncioAtual: action.payload }),
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [fetchAnuncios.fulfilled]: (state, action) => fullfillAnunciosReducer(state, action.payload),
    }
})

export const { setKeyAnuncioAtual } = anunciosSlice.actions

export default anunciosSlice.reducer
```

my main page (the one that's not rendering)
i consoled anuncios to debug

```
import Navbar from '../../layouts/navbar/Navbar'
import Card from './Card'
import PageTitle from '../../layouts/PageTitle'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export default function IndexPage() {
    const anuncios = useSelector(state => state.anuncios);
    console.log(anuncios);
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <PageTitle title={"Animais para adoção"} />
            <div className="container-fluid container-cards">
                <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center mb-5">
                    {anuncios.anunciosObjs.map((anuncio) => {
                        return <Card key={anuncio.key} anuncio={anuncio}/>;
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

[this is the result when i try to render the page for the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7q85.png)

Comment: Your `fetchAnuncios.fulfilled` reducer changes `state.anuncios` from an array to an object (look at the devtools) so you try to to map `state.anuncios.anunciosObjs` but your image does not show if that property even exist after your `fetchAnuncios.fulfilled` is run and it definitely doesn't exist before so it would error out on first render. You can either implement a loading value in your state or set initial state to `{anunciosObjs:[]}`

Comment: thank you kind sir. i changed the initial state and it works!